# SQLCMD Mode in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

I've started getting into the habit of switching to SQLCMD mode in SQL Server Management Studio when I'm deploying batches of SQL. I'm doing this so I can preface the SQL with

> :on error exit

I've forgotten to do this once and it took me a few minutes to clean up because some SQL had been run and there had been an error. I know I can set SQLCMD to be on by default, but my question is:

Is there any downside to setting SQLCMD Mode on by default? Do I lose any functionality in SSMS?

**Update 20190321:** I've been using SQL CMD Mode for about 9 months now and haven't experienced any issues with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-with-query-editor?view=sql-server-2017) from Microsoft states:

> Enabling SQLCMD mode turns off IntelliSense and the Transact-SQL
>   debugger in the Database Engine Query Editor.

I did find this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7411/are-there-any-reasons-not-enable-sqlcmd-mode-as-default-in-ssms) which was pretty relevant and helped provide some insight.

I'm going to enable it by [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-with-query-editor?view=sql-server-2017#enable-sqlcmd-scripting-by-default). The Intellisense in SSMS is a joke and I don't see the value in debugging SQL line by line when writing set based code.

**Update 20190409**
I did find that collapsible regions don't work in SQLCMD Mode; not a huge issue for me, but that might impact others' desire to use this feature.